# Manually selecting a feature in a map generated by d3.js (for the purposes of zooming in this case)

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to implement a map that zooms in on an area similar to Mike's click-zoom-example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590

In fact I have this working fine already. My problem is that I can't rely on the click event to implement the zoom — the zoom will be triggered by another event (a link). So when I get to this part of Mike's code:

```
function clicked(d) {
var x, y, k;

if (d && centered !== d) {
var centroid = path.centroid(d);
...
```

I'm a bit of a loss as I don't have 'd'. So, I'm assuming that I can instead, manually pass 'd' to my click function when I call it. But how do I actually select the feature (which is what 'd' represents) I want from the map?

To be a bit more concrete, I have a map of the world. The paths within the SVG group contain class information (e.g. the one for France looks like):

```
<path class="subunit FXX FRA" id="FXX" data-subunit="FXX" data-countryName="France" data-countryCode="FRA" d="M153.88838704622088,519........"></path>
```

How would I pass the 'France object' to the clicked(d) function? Or is there another approach altogether that I should be trying.

Any tips or help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data associated with the France object:

```
d3.select('.FXX.FRA').datum()
```

And pass it to clicked:

```
clicked(d3.select('.FXX.FRA').datum())
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't preserve the semantics of the click event handler. In particular, `this` won't be set to the current DOM object. This is not a problem in this particular case, but something to watch out for in general.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I was actually trying something like this but without the 'datum()' method so what I was seeing in the console was an array, not an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use D3's select for this purpose:

```
d3.select(".FRA").each(function(d) {
  // same code as inside clicked
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lars. I hadn't considered that approach but I tried it out and it works perfectly too. In my case, I decided to select Adam's answer because it just happens to be closer to my implementation. But as I progress on the project, I might come back to your suggestion.

Comment: No problem. For your purposes, both should be equivalent, with the caveat I posted as a comment to the other answer.